# Why this code is causing recomposition (jetpack compose)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I don't know why in my code the text where I type "hi" is always recomposed.
The text was fixed to "hi", and onClick also maintained the instance using uiEvent remember.

Even if uiState.isLoading is changed, it is not related to Text, so I expected that recomposition would be skipped, but recomposition always occurs when Text is changed.

Here is my code:

### UiState Data Class

```kotlin
data class UiState(
    val isLoading: Boolean
)
```

### UiEvent Interface.

```
@Immutable
interface UiEvent {
    fun onClick()
}
```

### Composable

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyScreen(
    viewModel: MyViewModel = hiltViewModels()
) {
    val uiState = viewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    val uiEvent = remember {
       object: UiEvent {
            override onClick() {
                viewModel.action()
            }
       }
    }
    Text(  // why recomposition?
        modifier = Modifier.clickable(onClick = uiEvent::onClick),
        text = "hi"
    )
    if (uiState.isLoading) {
        Text(text = "isLoading")
    }

}
```

Comment: FYI: https://dev.to/zachklipp/scoped-recomposition-jetpack-compose-what-happens-when-state-changes-l78

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume what you are asking is why does `Text` not skip whenever `MyScreen` recomposes. The reason is a new of the clickable modifier is being created every time. Consider remembering the entire modifier such as:

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen(
    viewModel: MyViewModel = hiltViewModels()
) {
    val uiState = viewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    val modifier = remember(viewModel) {
        val event = object: UiEvent {
            override fun onClick() {
                viewModel.action()
            }
        }
        Modifier.clickable { event.onClick() }
    }
    Text(  // why recomposition?
        modifier = modifier,
        text = "hi"
    )
    if (uiState.isLoading) {
        Text(text = "isLoading")
    }
}
```

Note the addition of the `viewModel` as a parameter to the remember to ensure a new version of `clickable()` gets created if/when the `viewModel` changes.

The compose compiler plugin should recognize the `::` syntax and do the `remember` for you, like it does for lambda syntax, but it doesn't right now. Also, the `clickable()` always returns a modifier that is not equal to the previous version for the same parameters, but that is going to be fixed in 1.5 (along with quite a number of other performance related fixes for `clickable()`). For now, you can work around these limitation by remembering the entire modifier.

Comment: Wow. I spend a couple of hours to find out that the clickable modifier is returning a new instance and therfore not fulfill the contract of `@Stable`. Thanks for the answer anyways. That helped a lot!

Comment: Not yet fixed in the 1.5.0 release

Comment: Which part? The part I said would be fixed in 1.5 is.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a simple layout with 3 texts:

- Static text with on click
- Static text
- Dynamic text (with clicks count)

[simple layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itwba.png)

This is how recompositions count looks after 3 clicks:

[recompositions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CVVg.png)

Clickable Text is recomposed every click. Tested on Compose BOM 2023.08.00

Workaround is to wrap clickable modifier with `remember` but I am not sure if it should be default way to use clickable Modifier.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).